# qemu + windows 10 strange behavior

Tags: arch-linux, windows, virtual-machine, qemu

My goal was to passthrough GPU to a windows 10 machine. After installing the system, I noticed that the resolution was awful and, unsurprisingly, the adapter was `standard vga graphics adapter` (or similar).

My first thought was that I failed to pass the GPU. I left the computer for a moment when all of a sudden the screen refreshed and `nvidia` was set as the display adapter.

I'm not a windows user so I'm asking the community - could this be considered as a normal behavior? Also, this happened only after I enabled networking so I guess it must be connected somehow.

Comment: This is really a Windows question so I won't put this as an official answer, but basically Windows detected new hardware and then went searching for the drivers and then installed them. It did require the networking that you enabled since it went and pulled the drivers from online. Sometimes it will take a good 10 minutes for that whole process.

Comment: Since the cause of the problem is not clear, I put it here. It might be my host linux system as well that has some impact on the guest windows machine.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you for the enlightment. @n8te

Comment: All good. I figured you might have initially thought it was a qemu issue causing it.

Comment: @n8te exactly...